# how to change a yyyy-mm-dd (string) to dd/mm/yyyy (date) in crystal reports 2016

Tags: crystal-reports

I am very new to crystal reports and I need help.
I have crystal connected to a sql database. the date field is coming to crystal as yyyy-mm-dd in a string format.
My main problem is when I try to filter this date field to CurrentDate it won't work.
Can I change it to mm/dd/yyyy in a date format? and how can I do that? [image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrJLx.jpg)

I appreciate your help
Thanks,
Rafik

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
cDate({yourDateStringField});
```

Comment: Where do i put that?